# how to add checkbox into uialertview?

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I'm new in iPhone development. I want to add a check box into an alert view. I'm doing tests on this alertview for the last two days, but do not get any working demo project. I want exactly this alertbox!

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: UIAlertView is pretty limited. you have to use  UIView, and present that modally

Comment: use this code to create custom Alertview https://github.com/goncz9/GRAlertView

Comment: Thank you for your support...but how can i add check button in this customview...?

Comment: Please make a custom AlertView for it... Means Use UIView Show Like alert view

Comment: what is the problem with a more iOS-conform solution here? like: `[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information" message:@"(blah)" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Remind me again" otherButtonTitles:@"Don't show me again", nil] show];`. that _don't show me_ checkbox reminds Windows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code for add checkbox in `alertview`.

**Swift**

```
let nameField = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50.0))
let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 40))
nameField.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox_off.png"), for: .normal)
v.addSubview(nameField)
var av = UIAlertView(title: "TEST", message: "subview", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "NO", otherButtonTitles: "YES")
av.setValue(v, forKey: "accessoryView")
av.show()
```

**Objective C**

```
UIButton *nameField = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 50, 50.0)];
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 40)];
[nameField setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[v addSubview:nameField];
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"subview" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
[av setValue:v  forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[av show];
```

i hope this code useful for you.

Comment: is it AppStore-safe? the `accessoryView` is not part of the public interface of the `UIAlertView`, and there is good reason why the `UIAlertView` cannot be customized in iOS7+ freely.

Comment: i don't know this code is valid in appstore . but this code work proprely in my code . you know so please tell me

Comment: it works, that is not a problem, but when someone'd like to submit an application with that solution, there might be rejected. that is why I've asked you about how many applications, which you published, did pass the review approval procedure with that solution? that is a very important detail to encourage or to avoid using such a solution.

Comment: ok thanks for this info . any other way for add checkbox in alertview is create custom alert ? right ?

Comment: unfortunately, yes, that would be much safer.

Comment: @holex okay but apple needs provide this functionality in ios 7 and other new versions.

Comment: you know as well that Apple provides what they want to provide to developers. the reason why there is no public access of the `UIAlertView` content in iOS7+ is that many applications cheated to change the content of the In-App Puchase official popup, especially the price, and the end-user saw less amount what they finally paid. that is why Apple forbids to access to the content of the official `UIAlertView` in future.

Comment: @holex ohhh that's reason. thanks for give me this information . thanks again.

Comment: Not working anymore in iOS 17

Answer (score 0):

iOS version independent

```
-(void) showAlert {
    isReemeber = TRUE;
    rememberButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [rememberButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"] 
                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rememberButton setTitle:@" Don't show me again" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rememberButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleRememberMethod) 
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [v addSubview:rememberButton];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmation" 
                                                    message:@"" 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

        v.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 40);
        rememberButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 250, 50.0);
        [rememberButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] 
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        alert.message = @"Message here";
        [alert setValue:v  forKey:@"accessoryView"];

    } else {

        v.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 250, 40);
        rememberButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 250, 40.0);
        alert.message = @"Message here\n\n\n\n";
        [alert addSubview:v];

    }
    [alert show];

}


-(void)toggleRememberMethod {
    if (isReemeber) {
        [rememberButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] 
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        isReemeber = FALSE;
    } else {
        [rememberButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"] 
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        isReemeber = TRUE;
    }
}
```