# checkbox in uialertview in ios8

Tags: ios, iphone, checkbox, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I want to add checkbox exactly as the below image

[image: Expected behaviour]

below is my code:

```
UIButton *nameField = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 0, 30, 30.0)];
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 50)];
[v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[nameField setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[v addSubview:nameField];
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete selected pods from server?" message:
                   @"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[av setValue:v  forKey:@"accessoryView"];
av.message = @"This will delete all the posts related to the pictures you want to delete!";
[av show];
```

with the above code I am getting as :

[image]

I want to get checkbox beside message..

Any help or suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: In iOS checkBoxes are not there. Instead of circle you can insert checkBox image. For that you need two images one is selected checkBox another one is unselected checkBox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727842/how-to-add-checkbox-into-uialertview

Comment: you should think about building the whole alert yourself to place the checkbox right beside the label because UIAlertView is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview
Create your custom content view and set it like

```
CustomIOS7AlertView *alertView = [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] init];

UIView *customView ..;  //Your custom view

[alertView setContainerView:customView];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do not do that.

1. `accessoryView` is not a public exposed API and you risk an app rejection
2. `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS8, use `UIAlertController`

You can use a third party library, I usually integrate [MRProgress](https://github.com/mrackwitz/MRProgress) in my projects, you can create your own nib and add it.