# How to add my custom UI component in the body of UIAlertController for iOS 9-10?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I need to add some extra `UI` component in the body of `UIAlertController` to create an alert like the following design.

[image: AlertController with Custom Body]

I did not find any public API from [Apples's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller). Can anyone help me to how to add the extra lable and checkbox in that alert body?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727842/how-to-add-checkbox-into-uialertview . If you are ok to use TPL there are lot of libraries available on github that can give you that option

Comment: Make it your own view and add all UIComponents whatever you want to add and Initially hide this view when you need then unhide that view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending an hour in the `debug view`, I was finally able to extract the `body` of an `UIAlertController` by the following code

```
let watingListAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Lista De espera", 
                                        message: "Algunos días seleccionados, no poseen disponibilidad en el chárter. Puede inscribirse a la lista de espera y el sistema lo tendrá en cuenta cuando algún espacio se libere\n\n\n", 
                                        preferredStyle: .alert)


if let alertContentView = watingListAlert.view.subviews[0].subviews.last?.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews[0] {

    // alertContentView is the view where title and message labels are drawn
    // Create your own UI Native components and add them on this view 
}
```

I was finally able to add the `extra label` and `check box` on the body of the `UIAlertController`. You can see my full project at [GitHub](https://github.com/sauvikatinnofied/AlertControllerCustomBody). I have created a gif of the final result.

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: how did you set or specify the extra space for the label and checkbox to appear below the UIAlertController's message text and above the two action buttons?

Comment: @PatNeedham Did you find a solution? That is exactly my problem. My custom content is over the action buttons